How do I disable gzip compression in micronaut 3.9.x?
Newer micronaut versions have settings to disable compression in responses by setting the compression-threshold = -1 or compression-level to 0.  Older versions don't support this in the DefaultHttpCompressionStrategy.

The workaround is to create a CustomHttpCompressionStrategy as follows:
@Primary
@Singleton
public class CustomHttpCompressionStrategy implements HttpCompressionStrategy {
  public boolean shouldCompress(io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse response) {
    return false;
  }

  public int getCompressionLevel() {
    return 0;
  }
}

